# front left brake clicking noise after changing gear

Tags: brakes, lexus

I have noticed that when I switch between straight and reverse, there is a clicking noise near the left front brake, when I let the car go for a few seconds then push the brakes. It's only one clicking sound then everything seems to be fine. If I go from straight to reverse (or vice versa) and drive for a few minutes and then push the brakes, there is no clicking noise.

The brakes and pads were changed last year.

Anyone know what could be the issues? thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model of the vehicle in question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you checked that the wheel nuts are tight?